# Point division Elliptic Curve in Java

Tags: elliptic-curve

Suppose I have `G(x,y) = k.P(x,y)`. I know `G(x,y)` and `P(x,y)`.
How do I calculate `k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `G(x,y)` and `P(x,y)`are on a secure elliptic curve for ECC, the problem of solving k is called "elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem", or ECDLP. It is infeasible to find k on a secure elliptic curve.

If you're not on such curve, enumerating all possible `k` and see if G=kP is a reasonable approach.